# Docker is stuck on "download complete" for pull

Tags: docker

I was following [this tutorial](http://dylanlindgren.com/docker-for-the-laravel-framework/) on linux (archlinux) when I was trying to do
`docker pull dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm` and I'm always stuck on the "*Download complete*" phase".

Full output:

```
➜  ~  docker pull dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm
61b3964dfa70: Pull complete 
f5224fc54ad2: Pull complete 
915f13277357: Pull complete 
0c908f87abb0: Pull complete 
a5051de47250: Pull complete 
26d211498b4b: Pull complete 
652ffa6008e4: Pull complete 
9605624da9d2: Pull complete 
c1876b9df357: Download complete
```

I actually waited for about half an hour (on 300Mb/s bandwidth), but nothing changed. Other images (like `ubuntu 14.04` or `dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-data`) are working fine.

I just noticed that `dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-data` says

```
Pulling repository  docker.io/dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-data
```

and there is nothing like that for `dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm`

So what am I doing wrong, or is it normal? I need to Ctrl+C it, restart docker, remove corrupted images and restart the operation every time.

Some references:

```
➜  ~  docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.5.1
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3-dirty
 Built:        Mon Sep 14 12:09:36 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.5.1
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3-dirty
 Built:        Mon Sep 14 12:09:36 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

UPDATE: the image seems to be ok (it works for other people, just not for me), so is there any way to debug what happens? Why does it stop on "Download complete" and doesn't do "Pull complete" ?

Comment: I tried and it worked for me. I have docker 1.7 on OS X. You may want to try to pull debian:jessie image to see if that works. I looked at the docker-laravel-data Dockerfile and basically it pulls this debian image and create a directory and volume.

Comment: docker-laravel-data works well, it's docker-laravel-phpfm that is stuck at "Download complete". debian:jessie was pulled in seconds and works as expected.

Comment: worked for me `docker pull dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm
61b3964dfa70: Pull complete 
...
652ffa6008e4: Pull complete 
9605624da9d2: Pull complete 
c1876b9df357: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:c2f59ebfadef87fcd5eb041087646e35ad9abbf1e0b44e4a87b8568e05901192
Status: Downloaded newer image for dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-phpfpm:latest
`

Comment: my version `docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2-rc1
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   28220ac
 Built:        Thu Sep  3 19:15:10 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2-rc1
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   28220ac
 Built:        Thu Sep  3 19:15:10 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`

Comment: So it doesn't seem to be a problem with image. I removed all images/containers, restarted docker and still no luck with the pull. So is there any way to debug this problem?

Comment: This happened on one instance that run out of space on the filesystem.
No message/error was shown.